# Find and filter to current year employees anniversary date using DATADD and CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, dateadd

i am trying to find the employee anniversary dates in increments of 5 year, 10 year 15 yea and so on, which i was able to get results but i am trying to filter the 'Anniversary_Year column created in the case statement to only show results of the current year, no past or future results needed just what is coming up.

```
SELECT Employee,Hire_Date
CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(year, 5, Hire_Date) >= GETDATE()
    THEN DATEADD(year, 5, Hire_Date)
    ELSE NULL 
END  AS '5_Year_Anniversary',
CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(year, 10, Hire_Date) >= GETDATE()
    THEN DATEADD(year, 10, Hire_Date) 
    ELSE NULL 
END  AS '10_Year_Anniversary',
CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(year, 15, Hire_Date) >= GETDATE()
    THEN DATEADD(year, 15, Hire_Date)
    ELSE NULL 
END  AS '15_Year_Anniversary',
CASE
  WHEN DATEADD(year, 25, Hire_Date) >= GETDATE() 
  THEN DATEADD(year, 25, Hire_Date)
  ELSE NULL 
END  AS '25_Year_Anniversary'
FROM
MyTable
WHERE YEAR(Hire_Date) = YEAR(getdate())
```

Comment: Modulo comes to mind.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask.  What's wrong with the result of your current query?

Comment: When we have `CASE`, we have no guarantee as to which case will be considered first.
Add conditions so that the values ​​do not accidentally fall somewhere else.
For example, if you worked 12 years, you can easily fall into condition 5 or 10.

Comment: *"When we have CASE, we have no guarantee as to which case will be considered first."* @KillerQueen? The `WHEN` expressions in a `CASE` are processed sequentially, by ordinal position. You know exactly which will be considered first. For an expression like `CASE WHEN {a} THEN ... WHEN {b} THEN ... WHEN {c} THEN ... ELSE ... END` the expressions `{a}`, `{b}`, `{c}` will be evaluated in that order, and no other. It is never "random". This is why the order of your `WHEN` expression is important.

Comment: my result show the anniversary dates that are coming up for the employees. but i want a shorter list and anniversary dates in the current year to display in the anniversary columns

Comment: @Larnu you have right, so  if you worked 12 years the statments return '5_Year_Anniversary'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `WHERE` clause to only return even 5 year anniversary rows.

```
SELECT Employee, Hire_Date,
       cast(YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(Hire_Date) as varchar(5)) + 'anniversary'
FROM MyTable
WHERE (YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(Hire_Date)) % 5 = 0
  and YEAR(getdate()) > YEAR(Hire_Date)
```

Comment: thanks! that works! what if i wanted to display the same type results for the 10 year, 15 year, and 25 year columns as well?